# Unable to get content of file using google drive api

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am working with a react application where you can access google drive files using react-google-picker and I am using [get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/get) api of google apis where you can pass "alt=media" as a URL parameter to get the file content. It's working as expected for text files but for PDF/Doc files, it returns metadata instead of actual content of file.
Is there any other way to get the content using google api's ??

this is the code for getting content of the file.

```
axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/${data.docs[0].id}?key=${developerKey}&alt=media`, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: Bearer ${this.state.token}
                }
            })
```

Comment: You linked to the Drive API v2. Are you sure that is the version. Also please share the code you are using to call the API for us to take a look and help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Saurabh, could you share some code, so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: @MarioVarchmin I have added the code. Please take a look.

Comment: @Aerials Actually I have tried Drive API v2 and v3 as well still got the same results.

Comment: Your issue maybe related to mime-type or Content-Type. Did you read this: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads?